# Navigation from one Place to another in GWT

Tags: gwt

I am new to GWT and presently developing a web application using GWT-MVP. Here I have to change the place when I click on a "Submit" button.

Any help/advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[GWT Places & Activities official documentation: How to navigate](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html#How_to_navigate)